# Remove square brackets from string

Tags: javascript, string

I want to process some text to remove any substrings in square brackets, e.g. converting this:

> We noted that you failed to attend your [appointment]  last  appointment .
>   Our objective is to provide the best service we can for our patients but [we] need patients’ co-operation to do this.  Wasting appointments impedes our ability to see all the patients who need consultations.  [If] you need to cancel an appointment again we would be grateful if you could notify reception in good [time].

To this:

> We noted that you failed to attend your last  appointment .
>   Our objective is to provide the best service we can for our patients but need patients’ co-operation to do this.Wasting appointments impedes our ability to see all the patients who need consultations.you need to cancel an appointment again we would be grateful if you could notify reception in good.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex....

```
var strWithoutSquareBracket = strWithSquareBracket.replace(/\[.*?\]/g,'');
```

The regex here first matches `[` and then any character until a `]` and replaces it with `''`

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2X4zA/2/)

Comment: yes it work but i also does not want text inside[].example [appointment] replace with"". thanks 
iJay .please help me

Answer (score 3):

Check this, it will help you:

```
var strWithoutSquareBracket = "Text [text]".replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');

alert(strWithoutSquareBracket);
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/2X4zA/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `text` is the variable name that holds your text. From your example, it seems you want to remove all text between square brackets (along with said brackets), so you'll have to write this:

```
text = text.replace(/\[.+?\]/g, '');
```

The `\[` matches the 1st bracket; then `.+?` matches any characters until the closing bracket (matched by `\]`). The `g` in the end tells `replace` to apply the regex to all the text.

Comment: I want to ask one things more i also want to remove more then one space come between the two word . eg  failed  to attend .In string text.how to remove ? thanks for helping me

Comment: please any idea to remove white space more then one from text ?

Comment: See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/B4x9R/). In it we first get rid of any double spaces (line 3) and then we take care of any punctuation that could have a space before it (line 4).